# Trouble with img size in smartphone screen

Tags: css, media-queries

I made a little wordpress website and in the smart phone screen my header image does not appear as I'd like.

The website is here : [here](http://www.aroadlife.eu/)

I tried to apply this code to the img div : 
`margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;`

Now the image size is great but I have a grey div beside which I don't want..

Here is what I get : 
[image]

Someone has idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. Which device/browser are you seeing an issue?

Comment: it's seems a cache issue

Comment: all of them, but particularly in iPhone 6/7/8 on Google Chrome browser to make a test @Jack

Comment: I deleted it.. but does not seem to work.. I updated my post with the result I get @TemaniAfif

Comment: try `object-fit: cover;` on the `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this (around line 1651 ):

```
.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
    display: table;
    height: 75vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

with this:

```
.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
    display: table;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks but it's not working, when I applied it, I have a really small image which is something like 10px height only...

Answer (score 0):

on mobile screen add these properties:

```css
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img, .has-header-video .custom-header-media video, .has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe, .has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .custom-header-media img { 
element.style {
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 75vh;
    width: 236vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add one line into your code:

```
#wp-custom-header img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

**Note:** this will stretch the image in -webkit browsers, the next step would  be to center your image, if you want to.

Cheers

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work the image is too big.. I'd like the image to be normal width (so 100% for width, and the height will be consequent to that)... @Bögözi